# AngularJS - Set Checkbox on Checked when Value is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

i got a user json object:

```
var users = [
    {
        firstName: 'Sven',
        lastName: 'Butzbak',
        userID: '1', // TODO refactor to _id
        gender: 'male',
        avatar: 'imageurl',
        notice: 'Fast fertig mit Theorie',
        'types': [
            {
                'type': 'am',
                'title': 'AM',
                'icon': 'am',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
                'check': [
                    {
                        'id': '1',
                        'name': 'Motor anlassen',
                        'value': 'false'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'Los fahren',
                        'value': 'true'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '3',
                        'name': 'Spiegel einstellen',
                        'value': 'true'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '4',
                        'name': 'Vorgespräch',
                        'value': 'false'
                    }
                ],
                'rating': [
                    {
                        'id': '1',
                        'name': 'Ausfahrt verlassen',
                        'rating': '1'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'Pokemon zocken beim Fahren',
                        'rating': '2'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '3',
                        'name': 'Mitbürger beleidigen',
                        'rating': '3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'type': 'a1',
                'title': 'A1',
                'icon': 'a1',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
                'ckeckCategory': [
                    {
                        'id': '1',
                        'name': 'Motor anlassen',
                        'value': 'true'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'Los fahren',
                        'value': 'false'
                    }
                ],
                'ratingCategory': [
                    {
                        'id': '1',
                        'name': 'Ausfahrt verlassen',
                        'rating': '1'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '2',
                        'name': 'Pokemon zocken beim Fahren',
                        'rating': '2'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': '3',
                        'name': 'Mitbürger beleidigen',
                        'rating': '3'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'type': 'a2',
                'title': 'A2',
                'icon': 'a2',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'a',
                'title': 'A',
                'icon': 'a',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'b-bf17',
                'title': 'B-BF17',
                'icon': 'b-bf17',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'b96',
                'title': 'B96',
                'icon': 'b96',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'be',
                'title': 'BE',
                'icon': 'be',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'c1',
                'title': 'C1',
                'icon': 'c1',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'c1e',
                'title': 'C1E',
                'icon': 'c1e',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'c',
                'title': 'C',
                'icon': 'c',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'ce',
                'title': 'CE',
                'icon': 'ce',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'd1',
                'title': 'D1',
                'icon': 'd1',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'd1e',
                'title': 'D1E',
                'icon': 'd1e',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'd',
                'title': 'D',
                'icon': 'd',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'de',
                'title': 'DE',
                'icon': 'de',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 't',
                'title': 'T',
                'icon': 't',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            },
            {
                'type': 'l',
                'title': 'L',
                'icon': 'l',
                'minAge': '16 Jahre',
                'include-classes': 'keine',
            }
        ],
        'events': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'Fahrstunde',
                'date': '26.07.2016',
                'time': '08:45'
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'Theorie Stunde',
                'date': '29.07.2016'
            }

        ]
    }
];
```

View in that i want to repeat Check:

```
<ul class="user-progress check" ng-repeat="types in  user.types">
    <fieldset class="standard">
        <legend>Fragen</legend>
        <li ng-repeat="cat in  types.check">
            <div>{{cat.name}}</div>
            <div>
                <md-checkbox ng-model="cat.value">
                    {{cat.value}}
                </md-checkbox>
            </div>
        </li>
    </fieldset>
</ul>
```

What i found on Angular Material Website (I Shorten the Code): http://codepen.io/BamiGorengo/pen/KrGQEw

Here it works, the Checkbox is Checked when the Page Loads. I understand that it comes from the $scope.data = {}; When i remove in the codpen website, then the checkbox dont show the correct style to...

I tryed to add to my userService:

```
$scope.types.check.value = {};
```

But this dont help... My JavaScript Skills are realy Bad.

Comment: You can't do "types in  user.types" because user does not exist. Users is an array of users. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I got alot of diffrent types. And in each type we got 2 Categories that i want to repeat. "check" and "rating" Depends what type i select in a select box, i want to display from a type the "check" and "rating" entries from the user. http://thommessen.upperyard.de/#/profile/1/sonstiges here you can see in live what i got now, maybe this helps to understand.

Comment: I understand. But your users is an array. You need user = {...}, not users = [{...}]

Comment: You are totaly right. i got in the service some other stuff that translate users to user... sry for this. absolutly my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single Quotes by the value field :) 'value': 'false'  => 'value': false

Comment: If the data is retrieved from a server in that specific format, user will not be able to change the type of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your type.value is not a boolean, it is a string. This means that the first time it loads the checkboxes, it does not recognize the strings 'true' and 'false' as booleans. Try this:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="cat.value" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
```

And check https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCheckbox for more info as to what this does.

Or make the values booleans instead of strings if you can.

Comment: Thanks alot! this was the problem. i made: 'value': 'false' with the ' ' but corret is it without ' ' like this: 'value': false

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure if the data you had was sent to you in that format. If you could change 'true' to true then you dont need ng-true, but if your data is dynamic and it comes as a string then you would need to implement ng-true

Comment: i dont use now the ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" because im still structuring the json shema. i just change the string to boolean.